# Symfony: How to configure embedded form to create new child object?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm building a user management page where I create or edit users.

The user consists of two entities, **user** and **profile**, which have a one to one relationship (I would merge, but can't for historical reasons).

/* User.php - Entity Class

```
/**
 * @var Profile
 * @Assert\Type(type="App\Entity\Profile")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $profile;
```

/* Profile.php - Profile Entity Class

```
/**
 * @var \App\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

I built two forms.

One form is the **profile** form which contains all the essential profile fields (first_name, last_name, email), although does not explicitly contain the relation field (user_id).

The other form is the **user** form, which contains the basic user fields (username, password), and also includes the profile form.

```
    $builder->add('profile', ProfileForm::class);
```

When I use this form for editting, everything works fine, and changes to both objects persist.  But when I try to use the form to create a new user, it fails, saying that I'm missing ***user_id***.

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null
```

It seems like this should work, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Typically this sort of problem occurs if Profile::setUser is never called.

Comment: It's not clear to me where that is called.   Once I validate the form, I call a persist on the user object, and that's where it throws the integrity constraint.   I thought the configuration of the relation of the user and profile would then automatically call that setter.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Curiously, I added an explicit setUser call to more store method, after validation:              

$user->getProfile()->setUser($user);

And it worked.  Still feel like this should be getting called elsewhere.

Comment: In general, you would call it in User::setProfile().  It's a common mistake to think the doctrine will automatically link two objects during creation.

Comment: That got me there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cerad for this answer.   I was not setting the link in my User entity setProfile class.

```
/**
 * Set profile
 *
 * @param \App\Entity\Profile $profile
 *
 * @return SfGuardUser
 */
public function setProfile(\App\Entity\Profile $profile = null)
{
    $this->profile = $profile;
    $this->profile->setUser($this);  // Adding this line fixed my issue

    return $this;
}
```